# dynamically build a html color enhanced list using vueitify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this code

```html
     <div class="row form-group" v-for="(author, key) in authorData" :key="key">
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex xs1 sm1 md1 text-xs-center>                   
                <div>
                  <v-checkbox
                    label
                    :key="author.PmPubsAuthorID"
                    v-model="authorData[key].checked"
                    v-bind:id="author.PmPubsAuthorID.toString()"
                    color="success"
                    @change="authorCBClicked(authorData[key])"
                  ></v-checkbox>                 
                </div>
                <!-- </v-card-text>
                </v-card>-->
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs10 sm10 md10>
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-text class="px-0">
                    <b>Author:</b>
                    <template v-if="author.Last_Name">{{' ' + author.Last_Name +' '}}</template>
                    <template v-if="author.Initials">{{author.Initials + ' '}}</template>
                    <template>
                      <br />
                      <b>Program:</b>
                      <b>
                        <font color=" + author.color + ">{{' ' + author.ProgramCode}}</font>
                      </b>
                    </template>
                    <br />
                    <template v-if="author.Affiliation">
                      <b>Affiliation:</b>
                      {{' ' + author.Affiliation}}.
                    </template>
                    <br />
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs1 sm1 md1 text-xs-center>                    
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </div>
```

inside a .  I am building the elements in the loop and I would like to have the Program_Code display in the color that is assigned to that program.  Each separate program is different. I posted a simular question that help me greatly in a different area with HTML formating at [HTML in a Vuetify v-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316865/html-in-a-vuetify-v-dialog/57317065#57317065)
but this is a different problem.  How can I get the author.ProgramCode to have the font color?  Do I need to build what was the answer on the other StackOverflow tread in a dynamic array? or closer to [Dynamic v-model don't complete inputs using v-html directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54168854/dynamic-v-model-dont-complete-inputs-using-v-html-directive)

Thanks

Comment: do you want to show a text using the given color `author.color`?

Comment: Yes-- like CC in Green and CM in Red and ZY in Blue.  The color that is stored in the database for that program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to show the text using data provided as Boussadjra mentioned, then you can do the following (In Vue, you can bind style to objects. This is what the code is doing):

```html
<span v-bind:style="{ color: author.color }">{{' ' + author.ProgramCode}}</span>
```

Note that the font tag is not supported by HTML5.

Comment: this just needs proper style binding :style

Comment: I substituted this line of code  <font color=" + author.color + ">{{' ' + author.ProgramCode}}</font> with your and I don't get the text in color.  Is there something else I need to do?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Even if I change <span style="{ color: author.color }">{{' ' + author.ProgramCode}}</span>  to <span style="{ color:Red }">{{' ' + author.ProgramCode}}</span> it does not change

Comment: OK added : to style and it worked-- smile  That's why I love Vue you can spend hours trying to find the solution but thanks to you folks it is worthwhile.

Comment: Ah yes and as @JaySwann said it actually should be v-bind:style or :style